# how can I define sequence of used ID?

Tags: excel, sequence, countif

I have ProductID:

```
ProductID
12
85
14
14
14
17
65
65
```

I need to create a new column where i could count how many times i have the same ProductID. I mean:

```
ProductID   Count
12           1
85           1
14           1
14           2
14           3
17           1
65           1
65           2
```

The formula I currently have is `= IF((A3=A2),F2+1,1)`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: i have tried = IF((A3=A2),F2+1,1), but it does not work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this formula if you want the count of each individual entry to be same. (i.e count for 14 will be 3 as it exists three times in the data set)

> =COUNTIF($A$2:A9,A2)

Output is attached for your reference.

[image]

Comment: Thank You very much, Irum :) it's very helpful, The first answer was exactly what i wanted. Thank You again :)

Answer (score 0):

In **B2** enter:

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:A2,A2)
```

and copy down

[image]